# Is it possible to centre a footer box in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have created a HTML/CSS website, but I have a problem, and I don't know how to fix it.
So, I would like the footer to be centered according the center of the website, but I don't know how to make it. Can somebody help me?

Files: https://github.com/TrainyBIG/help
Website: https://trainybig.github.io/help/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Centering Footer With CSS/HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942315/centering-footer-with-css-html)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not post links to external files. If those files get updated or links removed, this question becomes useless to future visitors. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I believe that this question has been asked before, and you haven't looked hard enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.footer {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 75%;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    font-family: "Exo", sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

You can use flexblox in order to align items in a one-dimensional way. I used the width you've given the body of your page (75%).

Comment: Hi, i have got another problem regarding this question. On another page i get this erros - https://trainybig.github.io/help/addons.html

Comment: The footer overlaps.

Comment: Why don't you put the footer inside the whole `container` class?

Comment: Because i want a kind of "space"

Comment: space to which element? Normally, you can add space as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Give some width in % for the footer class and 
margin : 0px auto

Comment: Does not work. Please if it is posible, show an coded answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer {
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    width: 850px;
}

#footer .social {
    float: left;
}

#footer .social ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#footer .social li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#footer .social img {
    border: 0px;
}

#footer .copyright {
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    line-height: 32px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

#footer .resize {
    float: right;
    width: 400px;
}
```